# Entity Framework - many to many related data loads into the navigation property collection, properties contain nulls except for the Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the many to many relationship below:

```
public class Student {
  public int StudentId { get; set; } 
  public string StudentName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course {
  public int CourseId { get; set; } 
  public string CourseName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The database migration creates a Junction Table named StudentCourse.

Using Eager Loading to load the data:

```
var student = context.Students 
    .Include(x => x.Courses) 
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

My observations:

- student.Courses.count = 5
- student.Courses[0].CourseId = 1
- student.Courses[0].CourseName = **null**

Why is the Courses.CourseName property null?

Comment: Stupid question but is it null in the database?

Comment: Wow, not stupid at all; entirely correct! Make this an answer, please, so I can mark it. It's embarrasing to not have noticed that. It looks like extra rows are being inserted into the Courses table (with an Id, but null CourseName) when seeding the students.Courses data.  Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not sure what I could put really, glad to have helped though. You could post another question regarding what is going wrong in the seeding?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because of your comment, it made me look at the seeding, and I was inserting new objects into Student.Course instead of inserting references to the existing objects.  All good now!